# Qlikview - join two table

Tags: join, qlikview

i need to join two table in Qlikview to get result.

Table:
[image]

I need to join this two table to get result table like this

[image]

Any idea? Can i use cross table and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Table1` you can use `CrossTable` functionality to "rotate" the table but keeping the first column.

For example:

```
CrossTable(Location, Quantity)
Load 
  Reason, 
  LocA, 
  LocB
From 
  [Data.xlsx] (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Table1)
;
```

The result table after this will be:

```
Location    Reason  Quantity
LocA        R1      5
LocA        R2      4
LocA        R3      5
LocA        R4      3
LocB        R1      2
LocB        R2      2
LocB        R3      3
LocB        R4      5
```

(you can learn more about `CrossTable` at Qlik's help site - [CrossTable](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/crosstable.htm))

After having `Table1` in this format you can create `composite key` (as x3ja suggested). `Composite key` is basically two (or more) fields concatenated. In your case the join between the tables should be on two fields - `Location` and `Reason`.

```
// CrossTable the data to get it in correct format
Table1_Temp:
CrossTable(Location, Quantity)
Load 
  Reason, 
  LocA, 
  LocB
From 
  [Data.xlsx] (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Table1)
;

// Resident load to form the composite key
// based on Location and Reason fields
Table1:
Load
  Location & '|' & Reason as Key,
  Quantity
Resident
  Table1_Temp
;

// We dont need Table1_Temp table anymore
Drop Table Table1_Temp;

//Load the second table and create the same composite key
Table2:
Load 
  Location & '|' & Reason as Key,
  Location, 
  Reason, 
  Answer
From 
  [Data.xlsx] (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Table2)
;
```

After the reload your data model will look like:

[image]

And the data:

[image]

Notice that the values for `Answer`, `Location`, `Reason` are `null` in the bottom two rows. This is because the data in `Table2` (based on your screenshots) don't contains combination for `LocB and R2` and `LocA and R4` but `Table1` does.

If you want to keep only the combinations that are present in both tables then the approach is similar but with two differences:

- `Table2` should be loaded first
- use `keep` function to exclude the non common records for being loaded in `Table1`

(`keep` at Qlik's help site - [keep](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/Keep.htm))

If you want to see the script in action just comment the first tab and uncomment the second one in the [example qvw](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxjGsOE_3VoOeWNYRURuNzVFSWc/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.

1. Using association. Load Table 1 twice and concatenate, creating a composite key. So you'd end up with fields ReasonLocation and Quantity. Then load Table 2 creating the same composite key, giving you ReasonLocation, Location, Reason & Answer. Then the tables would associate on that composite key.
2. Using a join. Load Table1, left join in Table 1 based on Reason with an if statement like `if [Location] = 'LocA' then [LocA] else [LocB]`. That may need you to load it into a temp table first and do the if statement in a resident load.

You could also combine the two and join the tables in #1 based on the ReasonLocation field.

Hope that helps - sorry it's not fully worked through...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new in QLikview, I don't understend. Can you give me same example, please?